# Show 2 META Tags Randomly

Tags: php

I want to Show meta tag like in a page like..

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Hi Admin, How are you" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/hiadmin.jpg" />
```

and

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Hi User, How are you" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/user.jpg" />
```

The Issue -

I want to Show meta tag randomly like..

Hi Admin, How are you (9 out of 10 times)
Hi User, How are you (1 Out of 10 times)

how can i do this? totally confused :/

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is something like:

```
<?php
if (rand(1, 10) == 1){
?>
<meta property="og:title" content="Hi User, How are you" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/user.jpg" />
<?php
} else {?>
<meta property="og:title" content="Hi Admin, How are you" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/hiadmin.jpg" />
<?php }?>
```